# Emmet doesn't work inside string literal and quotes vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code, emmet

I've already added html to JavaScript in emmet json setting.
It works well but not inside template literal (`) quote (') and double quotes (").
Emmet doesn't work inside that. Please help

Comment: use Emmet outside a string and then paste it inside a string

Comment: VSC Emmet is open source, modify it and add a pull request

Comment: I wonder if the `editor.quickSuggestions` setting would help here - set the `strings` option to `on`?